# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried using .then response and .catch but nothing worked. I am getting the below error when running test script .

I dont want to use node-fetch method

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'

         
            },
        });
        const json = await response.json();
```

Can anyone able to tell me what i am missing here?

(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:12784) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (rejection id: 2)
(node:12784) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: `fetch` isn't built into node. is this running in the browser (if so which one) or in node?

Comment: It's running in node.

Comment: then install a node compatible fetch package.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` is not a javascript but a browser spec. See e.g. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for details on fetch.

The only solution is to use a node package as the mentioned [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) or use the default node `http` [lib](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request/). From the docs:

```
var http = require('http');

//The url we want is: 'www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
var options = {
  host: 'www.random.org',
  path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been received, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  //the whole response has been received, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
```